# SOAP Server for testing purposes

Tags: web-services, soap

I'm fairly new to web services. I have a requirement to create a SOAP client for my current employer. The issue is, the SOAP server is being built by our Vendor and is still many months away; however, I need to start building the client now. I've tried to find a way to easily build a SOAP server (I was hoping there was an online way of doing this) to return mock data in the format I need. I'd prefer not to actually have to code the server if it was at all possible.

I hope this makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapUI is a tool which (among other things) allows you to create SOAP mocks, which you can setup to prepare and build your SOAP client.

Once you create a basic mock using a sample service, you can customise the request definition to your needs.

https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/getting-started.html

You can also pass in a WSDL if you have one available.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) which now has the capability to easily create mock HTTP responses that can be JSON or XML.

This is explained more in this [blog post](https://hackernoon.com/api-consumer-contract-tests-and-test-doubles-with-karate-72c30ea25c18).